# Using <force:recordData> in a community does not show/edit all records

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, force-recorddata, sharing-sets

I have a community and I am developing a lightning component page to display a custom object record `Grant__c` in this community.

The custom object `Grant__c` is in `Private` sharing mode so only owners can see records, and I have added a sharing set in the community settings, to allow a user to view/edit all of it's parents account `Grant__c` records.

The problem happens when I use  in my components inside the community, I can view and and edit the `Grant__c` record that I own, but cannot view or edit the `Grant__c` record that I do not own. I get this error on the `recordUpdated` event:

> Error: We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may
>   have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system
>   error. Ask your administrator for help.

This is the relevant code:

**MARKUP:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" description="API field names of the grant" default="Id,Name,Website__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" description="Id of the current record" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="YH_Grant__c" description="data of this grant" />

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordEditor"
                      fields="{!v.fields}"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      targetFields="{!v.record}"
                      mode="EDIT"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"/>

</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
recordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {

    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;

    if(changeType === "LOADED") {
        console.log("LOADED!!!");
    } 
    else if(changeType === "ERROR") {
        // here I get this error 
        console.log('Error: ' + component.get("v.recordError"));
    }
},
```

This is the sharing set definition:

[image]

**QUESTION**

Why don't I see records that I do not own, although my parent account and their parent account are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting the access mapping to:

**User:Contact.Account = Grant:Account**

May be this can help.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but it does not work